Is the activation box allowed to hang across the entire life line or is stacking them a better option?
I'm trying to learn UML, and right now I'm focusing on sequence diagrams. I'm trying to represent this Java code in a diagram.

I'm very unsure about the activation boxes. Could somebody maybe provide something to read about them or give me some tips?

